# Angular V4.3, Interceptor doesn't catch request or response

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript, interceptor

I am working on a project with the follow configuration. Apologies that I am quite new to Angular  world.

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/upgrade": "^4.3.6",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.28",
"angular-font-awesome": "^2.0.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

I am trying to implement the inbuilt response interceptor that was released in 4.3 version.
I have interceptor service as following.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse }
  from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('---> status:', evt.status);
        console.log('---> filter:', req.params.get('filter'));
      }
    });
}
}
```

I have shared module implementation and I have interceptor declared in it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }
  ],
```

For some reason, I don't ever hit the intercept method/console.log in the method. I wonder what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated. FYI, I was using this tutorial to work on interceptors.

https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/

Comment: Just as a small note, you can either just say `Angular` or if you do want to include the version, do `Angular 4` since that's the version you are on. Saying `Angular 2 V4` is a bit confusing and not really right, since `Angular 2` refers to the second version of Angular.

Comment: @Johannes updated, thanks.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with you implementation, did you make sure that the you're making your requests via the new `HttpClient`?

Comment: @cyrix aah ok. I did forget that. After making change to `HttpClient` Now, I have different problem.   `.then(response => response.json());`  is now throwing error when I try to compile with the message "Property 'json does not exist of type 'Object'". Any idea on it?

Comment: Because the new `HttpClient` tries to resolve the right `content-type`, it alreaedy knows it's json, so `response => response.json()` isn't needed anymore.

Comment: @cyrix. Right on. Thanks man. Saved my day.